# Bragança → Porto Airport (OPO) transfer

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, portugal, opo

I am in need of the cheapest possible transfer solution within Portugal, from [Bragança](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragan%C3%A7a,_Portugal) to [Porto Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porto_Airport) (OPO). I have a few options to choose from (like public transport combinations), but since the flight departs in the early morning hours, it would be way easier to get a taxi. Note that there will be 6 passengers, each with large luggage.

Is there any local taxi company in Bragança that is capable of this kind of transfer? Or would, for example, Uber be a better choice?

I have searched for some websites, but since I am not a local, I don't know which ones to trust or not, so I am asking here for advice from more experienced travelers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you in Bragança at the moment?

Comment: Not at the moment. The date of potential transfer would be 11th of March, early morning

Comment: When in Bragança, go [here](https://goo.gl/maps/7N9fqzmxEQYnBdu76) and talk to the taxi drivers.  Ask them how much they would charge.  I would be surprised if it were less than 250 EUR.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo that seems like an answer